# Faster creation of large amounts of Labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a Picross solving program in winforms where the grid is to be resizable as to allow for different sizes to be solved. I've been using a `List<System.Windows.Forms.Label>` to hold a label for each square of the grid, but when I resize the grid to sizes above 15x15, it tends to take seconds in order to simply resize the grid. While I do not anticipate rapid switching of grid sizes to be a common occurrence, I was hoping for grids to not take 10 seconds just to populate with labels.

```
System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel PicrossGrid;
List<System.Windows.Forms.Label> PicrossGridLabel;

private void adjustGridLabel(int newSize)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Label[] temp = new System.Windows.Forms.Label[newSize*newSize]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < newSize; j++)
        {
            temp[i * newSize + j] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            temp[i * newSize + j].Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            temp[i * newSize + j].AutoSize = true;
            temp[i * newSize + j].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            temp[i * newSize + j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(i, j);
            temp[i * newSize + j].Name = "PicrossGridLabelC" + (i + 1) + "R" + (j + 1);
            temp[i * newSize + j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 30);
            temp[i * newSize + j].TabIndex = (i * 5) + j;
            temp[i * newSize + j].Text = "X";
            temp[i * newSize + j].TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            PicrossGrid.Controls.Add(temp[i * newSize + j], i, j);
        }
    }
    PicrossGridLabel = temp.ToList();
 }
```

I also placed `this.SuspendLayout();` in the function before that calls this to prevent slowdown from drawing, but it is still incredibly slow. Is there a better way to approach this problem or a possible oversight that I'm making?

Comment: You could have a new label class that inherits label and has all your common properties pre-filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maximize efficiency with a solution based on a `TableLayoutPanel`, avoid recreating all `Label` controls when the size changes. You could implement a scheme to add/remove controls as the size changes; this would perform faster but is more difficult to design.

Some suggestions to improve the efficiency of your *recreate* approach:

- Avoid repeating arithmetic: calculate `i * newSize + j` only once and assign the result to a local variable.
- Use `TableLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange` method instead of `TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add`. This may prevent a temporarily 'frozen' UI.
- Try setting `TableLayoutPanel.DoubleBuffered = true`. The purpose of this is to prevent flicker when there's a change to a significant UI area but it may also speed things up.

Comment: That fixed it! Resizing from 5x5 to 25x25 and back again was taking about 15 seconds before and now it's down to mere fractions of a second. Most of it might be attributed to setting it to doubleBuffered, but the rest was helpful. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of GDI if I understand your issue. Since Windows Vista, videocard driver model provides hardware acceleration of only a small subset of GDI operations. So, most of the GDI operations when you start to resize a window performed programmatically.

As I know, the only solution is WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You could also find considerable time saving by eliminating the array and then casting the controls collection to the list.

```
System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel PicrossGrid;
List<PiCrossLabel> PicrossGridLabel;

private void adjustGridLabel(int newSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < newSize; j++)
        {
                PiCrossLabel NewLabel = new PiCrossLabel();
                NewLabel.Name = "PicrossGridLabelC" + (i + 1) + "R" + (j + 1);
                TabIndex = (i * 5) + j;
                PicrossGrid.Controls.Add(NewLabel, i, j);
        }
    }
    PicrossGridLabel = temp.ToList();
 }

public class PiCrossLabel:Label
{
    public PiCrossLabel()
    {
        this.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 30);
        this.Text = "X";
        this.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;            
    }
}
```

On my system a 20X20 fills in about 4 seconds.